# Ajax response is null for word docs, fine for txt and pdf

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm attempting to use an ajax request to get a file via binary data, and then convert it into base64.  This works fine for txt and pdf files, but fails when I try a docx.  Response is null, and ResponseText is a DOMExpection.  If I go to the url directly in chrome, it downloads the file fin.  Is there anything special about docx files?  Here's my code.

```
function _arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
    var binary = '';
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    var len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
    }
    return window.btoa(binary);
}


function download(fileName, fileDownloadLocation) {
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.onload = function(data) {
        var base64str = _arrayBufferToBase64(this.response);
        //Do custom stuff here
    };
    oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    oReq.open("get", fileDownloadLocation, true);
    oReq.send();
}
```

I've also tried screwing with the Accept headers, but no luck.  I call this right after open.

```
oReq.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/octet-stream,text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8');
```

Comment: Have you tried using `onreadystatechange` instead of `onload`? I don't think `onload` is standard.

Comment: Yes, I've tried using onreadystatechange, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this only happens when files have a length of 0.

Comment: is this question closed ? did you find solution ?

Comment: Yes, this behavior occurred when the file size is 0.  I added a check for that.